# Angular - how do I make generic Add button to use in all child components?

Tags: angular

I am building a simple application where there is a toolbar in the top of the screen. In the toolbar there is a + button for adding content. Depending on which component is active this + button could should open a dialog to add a specific model.

Like, if I'm on the Users page/component and click the + button I should open the add user dialog (this is on the user component). And the same if I'm on the "company" page/company. That same button should now trigger the "create company" dialog.

That means that I have a generic button in a general toolbar, depending on what the current component is, that button should do something else.

I can't wrap my mind around how to do this. My best bet so far is to have a shared service with an observer/observable to relay the message. But that doesn't seem like the best approach. Is there anything im missing? Like subscribing to a message? Implementing interface methods or something?

Comment: You got it right. The right approach will be to use a shared service. Your components are undepended and don't know each other. In this case a shared service is the right way to go.

Comment: Why should a shared service have to be injected into every page/component? At that point, just put something on the route-

Comment: @OneLunchMan In case of huge amount of data?

Comment: Is that a guess or a response? We weren't provided enough context to provide an answer for that.
Anyways Brian, you can tie into the router-outlet's events to tell you what component activates with the route (and deactivates) and work with that. Here is a link that does a good job explaining.
https://netbasal.com/angular-2-router-routeroutlet-events-8b0803d88082

Comment: @benshabatnoam - but doesnt this approach open up to a whole lot of subscriptions? I mean in my ngOnInit i would subscribe. And every other component would also do this. Wouldn't this approach create a ton of subscribtions? - given that i use a behaviorSubject in the shared service?

Answer (score 0):

A Shared Service is a good way to apply this dynamic toolbar button click.

Each component will subscribe to this button click event by the shared service on `ngOnInit`, and will unsubscribe it on `ngOnDestroy`. This means that you'll have **only one** subscription at a time.

> Checkout this simple [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-service-so54388950)

---

**Example code:**

first.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { SharedService } from './shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  template: `<h1>This is first component</h1>`
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
  addSubscribe: Subscription;

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addSubscribe = this.sharedService.addClicked.subscribe(() => {
      alert('Add from First componenet');
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.addSubscribe.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

shared.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  addClicked = new Subject();
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { SharedService } from './shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onAdd(): void {
    this.sharedService.addClicked.next();
  }
}
```

I think this is a simple, easy to implement and a good solution in your case.